# Counting the number of calls to each service in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to count the number of calls to each api in wso2 api manager and I don't want to use analytics and monetization.
Is this value stored in the database?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to get this without analytics. Throtling related data should be maintained in JMS durable topics and should be stored in the default H2 database. But these will be reset from time to time. So you won't be able to get a cumulative count.
As a workaround how about adding a [custom Handler](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/#writing-a-custom-handler) that logs a record to a file or DB to count what you need? You can even use a [custom mediation policy](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-policies/create-policy/) to log the details and then use something like ELK to cont the logs and render them in a dashboard.

Also, you can use the default [API log](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/api-manager/monitoring-api-logs/) capabilities as well for this.